# qt boost header file linking in .pro file

Tags: c++, qt, boost

There are a lot of similar question out there but none could help me. I try to be very clear with what I did to make sure I do not miss any essential step:

I need to use the C++ boost headers in one of my Qt projects on Windows. I'm not very familiar with qmake and its `*.pro` files and neither with building and compiling using Windows.

1.) I did download the newest version of the boost libraries from [here](https://www.boost.org/users/download/). I choose the `boost_1_72_0.zip` file. I extracted the folder and found a folder named `boost` containing what I expect to be the header files. 
I copied the full content of the `boost` folder to `D:/programming/boost`

2.) My Qt project source code is located in `D:/programming/QtProject`. I'm now trying to tell my QtProject where the boost header libraries are located. I want to be able to include them via `#include <boost/date_time.hpp>`

I did add the following line to my `*.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../boost
```

but it still does not find the includes via `#include <boost/date_time.hpp>`.

However, I'm able to include the boost headers via `#include "../boost/date_time.hpp"` but then it does not find nested includes such as `#include "boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp"` inside the `date_time.hpp` file.

What is the right way to add the boost header files into my `*.pro` file to be able to include boost via `#include <boost/date_time.hpp>`?

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments the right way to include the boost libraries seems to be to include the parent directory of boost instead of the `boost` directory.

However, now I get the following error message:

```
:-1: error: LNK1104: Datei "libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden.
```

Not sure why it is in german. The translation of `Datei` would be `File` and `kann nicht geöffnet werden` is `could not be opened`.

**EDIT2:**

pretty sure it has to do with the optional build of boost::date_time. I try to fix it using `#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB`.

**My initial question was definitely answered by the comment**

Comment: Don't include `../boost` in your path, include the parent directory of the boost folder. That way, when you `#include <boost/date_time.hpp>` it will resolve to find boost folder.

Comment: That is, `INCLUDEPATH += d:/programming`

Comment: I'll try that immediately, I just need to copy the whole content of the `zip` file (so far I only copied the `boost` part)

Comment: @selbie consider adding a short answer so that I can accept it